# Replace multiple elements in a list

Tags: replacement

I have two lists, the first list has a large numerical data, and the other list has the position of elements of the first list that are zero. For example

```
s = {1, 5, 7, 8, 11 ,10, 3}
Zeroelement = {1, 3, 5}
```

I have tried use `ReplacePart[s2, Zeroelement  -> 0.0]`, but does not work.

I would like to replace the elements  1, 3, and 5 in "s" by 0 without using a loop. That's is possible?,

The lists have different lengths.

Answer (score 8):

it was very easy, simply do `s[[Zeroelement]]=0`

Answer (score 7):

It can be done with `ReplacePart` like this:

```
s = {1, 5, 7, 8, 11, 10, 3};
z = {1, 3, 5};
ReplacePart[s, Thread[{z}] -> 0]
```

> `{0, 5, 0, 8, 0, 10, 3}`

Answer (score 3):

**Using `MapAt`:**

```
s = {1, 5, 7, 8, 11 ,10, 3}
z= {1, 3, 5}
```

Since positions are given,

```
MapAt[0 # &, s, List /@ z]
```

> {0, 5, 0, 8, 0, 10, 3}

Answer (score 3):

In `v 13.1`:

```
ReplaceAt[s, _->0, Transpose[{Zeroelement}]]

(* {0, 5, 0, 8, 0, 10, 3} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`SubsetMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubsetMap.html) is a more convenient sibling of `MapAt`:

```
s = {1, 5, 7, 8, 11, 10, 3};
z = {1, 3, 5};

SubsetMap[0 # &, z] @ s
```

> ```
> {0, 5, 0, 8, 0, 10, 3}
> ```